# Finding the closest number that factors given a list of primes

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Say I have a number, I can find all the prime factors that make up that number. For instance, 6000 is 2^4 * 3 * 5^3.

If I have a number that doesn't factorize well (given a list of acceptable primes), how can I find the next closest number? For instance, given the number 5917, what is the closest number that factors with the list of primes 2, 3, 5, 7? Which is 6000 in this example.

I have something that will brute force find the answer, but there has to be a more elegant solution.

```
const UInt32 num = 5917;
const CVector<UInt32> primes = { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
const size_t size = primes.size();

UInt32 x = num;
while (x < num * 2)
{
    const UInt32 y = x;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size && x > 1; ++i)
    {
        while(x % primes[i] == 0)
        {
            x /= primes[i];
        }
    }

    if (x == 1)
    {
        cout << "Found " << y << endl;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        x = y + 1;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I created a test that used the brute force method and the 3 methods provided as answers and got somewhat surprising results. All 4 versions produce correct answers (so thanks for your contributions), however, the brute force method seemed to be the fastest, by an order of magnitude. I tried on a few different systems, compilers, and architectures which all yielded mostly consistent results.

The test code can be found here: http://ideone.com/HAgDsF. Please feel free to make suggestions.

Comment: The numbers 6000 and 5880 are both 2,3,5,7-smooth, and 5880 is closer to 5917 than 6000. Why is 6000 the correct answer?

Comment: @user448810 The answers already in place are taking "next closest number" to mean "next number higher" and OP hasn't rejected them

Comment: This problem (with abstract algorithmic solution) is discussed [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42243/next-restricted-b-smooth-number-problem).

Comment: Currently, we are using n approach of always going higher, but I am not sure that is necessary. If the closest one is lower, that may work, we have yet to do analysis.

Comment: I must be missing something. How is 6,000 the answer, when it's not even divisible by 7?

Comment: @JimMischel The answer does not **have to** factor with **all** primes listed, it may **only** factor with the primes listed. For instance, given 8189, the answer would be 8192, which is 2^13, even though 3, 5, and 7 are not required.

Comment: I think your choices of primes and test numbers has a lot to do with the timing you're getting. If the primes are much larger, brute force will slow way down. Will your list of primes always start at 2?

Comment: P.S. I made a couple of stylistic changes to your version that should make no difference to the correctness or run time: http://ideone.com/BvkLSD

Comment: @MarkRansom I do agree with you that the numbers chosen have some bearing on the speed. I only tested with primes: 2, 3, 5, and 7. That is because a library that we are calling works most efficiently with those primes (hence the question) and since they are all small, the nearest acceptable value is always pretty close based on the more exhaustive testing I did on my own, and thus the brute force is faster in that situation. That still does however surprise me, I never expected the brute force to work as well under most circumstances.

Comment: I did however want a design that was not restrictive to those specific numbers so the algorithm could still be used if anything ever changed. Also of note, on my main system, which is quite powerful, the recursive method was the second fastest most of the time, but most other systems it behaved much similar to the results shown in the example at Ideone.

Comment: @steveo225 here you go, I did my best to make a crude C++ fork of your test (I don't know C++) with a recursive version of my algo. The time for the third input seems faster than yours: http://ideone.com/OUsmOr

Comment: this post might go better with the folks over at [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the following solution. I assume that primes are ordered from lower to greater. I have also used convenient `vector` and `int` types.

```
vector<int> primes = { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
int num = 5917;
// initialize bestCandidate as a power of some prime greater than num
int bestCandidate = 1;
while (bestCandidate < num) bestCandidate *= primes[0];
set<int> s;
s.insert(1);
while (s.size()) {
    int current = *s.begin();
    s.erase(s.begin());
    for (auto p : primes) { // generate new candidates
        int newCandidate = current * p;
        if (newCandidate < num) {
            // new lower candidates should be stored.
            if (s.find(newCandidate) == s.end())
                s.insert(newCandidate);
        }
        else {
            if (newCandidate < bestCandidate) bestCandidate = newCandidate;
            break; // further iterations will generate only larger numbers
        }
    }
}
cout << bestCandidate;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/jZOGTZ)

Next I want to make an analysis of proposed solutions. Let me use *np* as a number of primes; *n* as a number to find the closest result to; *minP* as a minimum prime in the list.

1. My solution generates all possible values that are lower than *n*. New values are generated out of the old ones. Each value is used only **once** to be the generation source. If new value exceeds *n* it is considered as a valid candidate. In case the list will contain all the primes lower than *n* still the algo can perform well. I don't know pretty time complexity formula for the algo but it is the number of valid candidates lower than *n* multiplied by the log of previous factor. Log comes from `set` data-structure operations. We can get rid of Log factor if *n* can be small enough to allocate array of size *n* to flag which values were already generated, a simple list can hold generation source values instead of set.
2. Your initial solution has *O(n(np + log<sub>minP</sub>(n)))*. You check every number to be valid taking then one by one from *n* to *2n* paying *np + log<sub>minP</sub>(n)* for each check.
3. [Recursive solution by @anatolyg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36209237/1770952) has a big flaw in "visiting" some valid numbers many times which is very inefficient. It can be fixed by introducing a flags indicating that the number was already "visited". For example `12 = 2*2*3` will be visited from `6 = 2*3` and `4 = 2*2`. Minor flaws are numerous context switching and supporting the state of each call. The solution has a global variable which clutters global namespace, this can be solved by adding a function parameter.
4. [Solution by @dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36209264/1770952) lacks efficiency because already "used" candidates are taken for generation of the new candidates producing numbers already present in the set. Although I've borrowed the idea with set.

Based on the [@גלעד ברקן's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36240559/1770952) I've created a `c++` solution which is indeed seems to be asymptotically more efficient because there is no `log` factor. However I refused to work with `double` logarithms and left solution with integers. The idea is simple. We have a list of products lower than `num`. Each of the products is generated out of the first `primesUsed` primes. We then try to generate new products using next prime. Such approach guarantees to generate **unique** products:

```
vector<int> primes = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 23 };
int num = 100005917;
int bestCandidate = INT_MAX;
list<pair<int, int> > ls;
ls.push_back(make_pair(1, 0));
while (ls.size()) {
    long long currentProd = ls.front().first;
    int primesUsed = ls.front().second;
    ls.pop_front();
    int currentPrime = primes[primesUsed];
    while (currentProd < num) {
        if(primesUsed < primes.size() - 1)
            ls.push_back(make_pair(currentProd, primesUsed + 1));
        currentProd *= currentPrime;
    }
    bestCandidate = min((long long)bestCandidate, currentProd);
}
cout << bestCandidate;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Lf1sCM)

Comment: I think your analysis fits well with the results I am seeing. Your version does seem to be the most efficient under a more wide variety of inputs.

Comment: @steveo225 Ivan, I think my algorithm has a similar idea to yours but mine generates only the distinct combinations without needing a set for memoization, check it out! Compare the number of iterations in yours vs mine for the three examples in steveo225's test code: target 5917: yours 836, mine 448; target 8192: yours 948, mine 491; target 262145: yours 2895, mine 1048.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to arrive at the answer by repeated factoring, you could try generating all possible products until you enumerate all products under `target*minPrime`, where `minPrime` is the smallest prime in your set.

Start with a set consisting of `1`. Each iteration tries multiplying each number in the current set by each prime. If a new number under the max is found, it is added to the current set. The process repeats itself until no new numbers can be added.

In your case, the first generation would be

```
1 2 3 5 7
```

The next generation would be

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 14 15 21 25 35 49
```

After that you would see

Generation 3

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 14 15 18 20 21 25 27 28 30 35 42 45 49 50 63 70 75 98 105 125 147 175 245 343
```

Generation 4

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 14 15 16 18 20 21 24 25 27 28 30 35 36 40 42 45 49 50 54 56 60 63 70 75 81 84 90 98 100 105 125 126 135 140 147 150 175 189 196 210 225 245 250 294 315 343 350 375 441 490 525 625 686 735 875 1029 1225 1715 2401
```

and so on. After twelve generations your set would no longer grow, at which point you could find the smallest value above the target.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/jS9Aug)

Answer (score 2):

The idea is, to check all possible products of acceptable primes, and choose the best.

To implement that, it's easiest, though probably not most efficient, to use recursion. Make a recursive function that "checks" a temporary product by adding all acceptable primes, one by one. To remember the best result, it's easiest to use a global variable.

```
int g_result;

void check(int num, int product, const vector<int>& primes)
{
    if (product >= num)
    {
        g_result = std::min(g_result, product);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int prime: primes)
            check(num, product * prime, primes);
    }
}

...
int main()
{
    g_result = INT_MAX;
    vector<int> primes = { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
    check(5917, 1, primes);
    std::cout << g_result;
}
```

The usage of a global variable is an ugly hack; it's good enough in this simple example, but not good for complicated (multi-threaded) systems. To eliminate the global variable, stuff the function into a class and make it a method; and use a member variable `result` instead of a global one.

Note: I used `vector<int>` instead of `CVector<UInt32>` for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the logarithm, we can look at this as a variant of the subset sum problem. Here's a JavaScript example that enumerates distinct combinations that just pass the target mark.

```js
function f(target,primes){
  target = Math.log(target);
  primes = primes.map(function(x){ return Math.log(x); });

  var best = primes[0] * Math.ceil(target / primes[0]);
  var stack = [[0,0]];

  while (stack[0] !== undefined){
    var params = stack.pop();
    var t = params[0];
    var i = params[1];

    if (t > target){
      if (t < best){
        best = t;
      }
    } else if (i == primes.length - 1){
      var m = Math.ceil((target - t) / primes[i]);
      stack.push([t + m * primes[i],i + 1]);
    } else {
      t -= primes[i];
      while (t < target){
        t += primes[i];
        stack.push([t,i + 1]);
      }
    }
  }

  return Math.round(Math.pow(Math.E,best));
}

console.log(f(5917,[2,3,5,7]));
```

Comment: Your idea allows to write really efficient solution. I have created a `c++` solution based on your approach. However I would not switch to `double`s as it brings some floating point errors, in order to compare two doubles an epsilon is required. For example, `f(10, [2,5])` will return `16`, not `10`.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko Thanks so much for checking it out and explaining about the logarithms!